# Chromedriver test work locally and on CI CD env python

Tags: python, azure-devops

What I have: CURRENT_BROWSER=chrome in Win Environments

```
def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    use_fixture(browser, context)


def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.cache.clear()
    context.driver.quit()


@fixture
def browser(context):
    browser_type = os.getenv('CURRENT_BROWSER', 'chrome')
    if browser_type is None:
        raise Exception(f"Unable to identify test browser which is {browser_type}")
    if browser_type == 'chrome':
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        # chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
        context.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=chrome_options.to_capabilities())
    if browser_type == 'firefox':
        pass

    yield context.driver
```

What I need is: the answer how to deal with the chromedriver on CI CD (azureDevops) should I also put ENV variable similar to Browser in to the PATH and do the same on CI CD or there is different way to deal with chrome driver. I need above code will work locally and on CI CD and I never did that before. Locally I use above code + chromedriver.exe added in to project structure

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? Please check whether my answer can help you and feel free to comment~

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent): `windows-latest`, `windows-2019` or `vs2017-win2016`, the Chrome Driver 87.0.4280.88 is already installed.

If you want to use another version of Chrome Driver, you can download it using npm:

```
- script: npm install chromedriver --chromedriver_version=LATEST
```

Click [this document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver) for detailed information.

If you are using a [Self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#check-prerequisites) and the agent is on a machine that has already downloaded the Chrome Driver and configured PATH, you can use Chrome Driver just as you work on your own machine.